# Match value in copy copy over value if there is a match

Tags: sql, null, match

I have 2 tables in my database

`Customers` table:

| Customer_id | Firstname | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123156 | John | Johnsen |

`Orders` table:

| OrderID | Firstname | Lastname | Customer_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9999999 | John | Johnsen | NULL |

I want to match the firstname and lastname column from both tables and fill in the `Customer_id` in the `customer_id` column in the `Orders` table if there is a match with the firstname and lastname

How can I do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update orders
    set customer_id = (select customer_id from customers c where c.firstname = orders.firstname and c.lastname = orders.lastname)
    where customer_id is null;
```

Comment: Getting this error:

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @Robert-JanKempink . . . That is a problem with your data model.  Apparently, you have customers with the same name.  **You** have to decide what to do about that.  You can get around the problem using `max(customer_id)` in the subquery.